# Imgur API collection

Tags: collections, postman, imgur

I would like to know if I can use the imgur API in my personal project. What I mean is that I want to create my own collection based on the Imgur REST API using Postman plus code some tests and push it to my GitHub account as a public project for my portfolio. Can I do this or is it illegal due to copyright/license infringement? I guess not cuz imgur is free unless you want to use it for commercial purposes but as I said this is not my intention.